# Python multithreading - interaction with child threads from parent/main thread

Tags: python, python-multithreading

We are using python multithreading(I/O bound) for our application deployments. From main/parent thread we are creating multiple child threads (multiple hosts [application/web] for deployment within each thread) and waiting for them to finish using .join() in main thread. We are also using some Fabric package commands to ask user input whether to proceed with deployment or not in-case of an error for whatsoever reason.

Problem statement:
Since we are using multithreading, all the child threads are writing the messages to terminal (stdout)output and thus the errors from one thread on the screen are overlapping by other thread messages and it is difficult to comb through the console/terminal to see what thread has failures.

What could be the best way to gather all the failure steps in the deployment from all the threads collectively and display all of them at once on the console/terminal output ?

The difficulty I'm facing is how to interact with child threads while in main thread we are just waiting to finish them (if there are any fabric user interactive questions then will type y/n based on our decision about the failure).

Comment: Perhaps you can break the work into multiple tasks. Suppose I want to do 5 things to 10 hosts. I break those into separate functions with a data structure holding state - perhaps as a class. I create a 10 worker thread pool then use `pool.map` for each step. I use the return from each step for larger questions such as whether I should continue.

Comment: The logging module might help you. You can create a logger for each thread and filter them with the helper function. It' a pretty powerful module with a lot of functionalities. To get a logger object: `logging.getLogger(name=some_unique_name)`. You can also choose where to output the message (stdout, file, etc.)

Comment: Thanks TwistedSim for the reply. We are creating logger in main thread but thats fine we can create another separate logger for each thread. How do I create/use the helper function and filter the failures/exceptions messages for all of the threads ?